# How can I split a string on a control character in ksh?

Tags: ksh

I need to split a string on a form feed character (\x0c) and then:

1. output the portion before it
2. do some logic
3. output the portion after it.

I am stuck with `ksh` for now.

I have tried setting `IFS=\x0C` and reading the string into 2 variables, but it fails to find the delimiter, with or without quotes, and puts the entire string including the delimiter into the first variable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
IFS=\x0C
```

you have set `IFS` to string `x0C`, not the formfeed `\f`.

In `ksh` (and also `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`), you can use:

```
IFS=$'\f'
```

or POSIXLY:

```
IFS=$(printf \\f)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to ksh programming.  Been writing code for 35 years, but usually in a higher level language.